# ¿Cómo agregar elemento a un arreglo?

Tags: c

He estado haciendo un programa en C que me ida ingresar 'n' elementos en un arreglo, posteriormente buscar un elemento dentro de él, borrar un elemento dentro de él, y agregar un elemento al final del arreglo.

El problema que tengo es con la última acción, la cual es agregar un elemento al final del arreglo.

Lo que ocurre es que, al agregar el elemento al arreglo, el elemento anterior a ese es completamente diferente al que inicialmente estaba.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void buscarElemento(int a[], int size_busca, int element_Busqueda);
void borrarElemento(int b[], int size_borra, int element_Borrar);
void agregarElemento(int c[], int size_agrega, int element_Agregar);

int main()
{
    int n; // Variable que determinará el número de elementos del arreglo.
    int i; // Variable para recorrer el arreglo.
    int elemento_Bus;
    int elemento_Borr;
    int elemento_Agre;

    printf("Ingresa el numero de elementos del arreglo: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int array[n]; // Creamos un arreglo de enteros, el número de elementos del arreglo
                  // será el número asignado a la variable 'n'.

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Ingresa el elemento numero %d del arreglo: ", (i+1) );
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Ingresa el elemento a buscar en el arreglo: ");
    scanf("%d",&elemento_Bus);

    buscarElemento(array, n, elemento_Bus);

    printf("Ingresa el elemento a borrar en el arreglo: ");
    scanf("%d",&elemento_Borr);

    borrarElemento(array, n, elemento_Borr);

    printf("\n");

    printf("Ingresa el elemento a agregar en el arreglo: ");
    scanf("%d",&elemento_Agre);

    agregarElemento(array, n, elemento_Agre);

    printf("\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void buscarElemento(int a[], int size_busca, int element_Busqueda)
{
    int j;
    int b = 0;
    int hold1,hold2;
    int cont = -1;


        for(j=0; j<size_busca; j++)
        {
            if(element_Busqueda == a[j])
            {
                hold1 = a[j];
                hold2 = j;
                b = 1;
            }
        }


    if(b==1)
    {
    printf("El elemento encontrado es %d y se encuentra en la posicion %d.\n",hold1,hold2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Elemento no encontrado.\n");
    }
}

void borrarElemento(int b[], int size_borra, int element_Borrar)
{
    int j;
    int c = 0;

    for(j=0; j<size_borra; j++)
    {
        if(element_Borrar == b[j])
        {
            b[j] = b[j+1];

            for(j=j+1; j<size_borra; j++)
            {
                b[j] = b[j+1];
            }
            --size_borra;
            c = 1;
        }
    }

    if(c == 1)
    {
        printf("El arreglo sin el elemento borrado anteriormente es:");

        for(j=0; j<size_borra; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d",b[j]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Ese elemento NO se encuentra en el arreglo.\n");
    }
}

void agregarElemento(int c[], int size_agrega, int element_Agregar)
{
    int j;

    c[size_agrega] = element_Agregar;

    size_agrega++;

    printf("El arreglo con el elemento agregado es: ");

    for(j=0; j<size_agrega; j++)
    {
        printf("%3d",c[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(j=0; j<size_borra; j++)
{
    if(element_Borrar == b[j])
    {
        b[j] = b[j+1];

        for(j=j+1; j<size_borra; j++)
        {
            b[j] = b[j+1];
        }
        --size_borra;
        c = 1;
    }
}
```

El código anterior está en la función `borrarElemento`. Si suponemos que tenemos un arreglo de 3 elementos: `1 2 3` y que queremos borrar el segundo elemento, este código hará lo siguiente:

```
j = 0 -> b[j] = b[0] != 2
j = 1 -> b[j] = b[1] == 2
  b[j] = b[j+1] <=> b[1] = b[2]
  j = j+1 = 1+1 = 2             <-- for(j=j+1 ...
  b[j] = b[j+1] <=> b[2] = b[3] <-- porque j<size_borra (2<3)
```

En esta última instrucción estás copiando en el tercer índice el valor almacenado en el 4º... el problema es que no existe un 4º índice. Estás copiando basura en el array.

Lo correcto aquí sería desplazar todos los elementos y llenar la última posición con un valor por defecto (por ejemplo 0)

```
if(element_Borrar == b[j])
{
    for(j=j+1; j<size_borra; j++)
    {
        b[j-1] = b[j];
    }
    b[j-1] = 0;
    --size_borra;
    c = 1;
    }
}
```

Ahora vamos a repasar la función `agregarElemento`:

```
void agregarElemento(int c[], int size_agrega, int element_Agregar)
{
    int j;

    c[size_agrega] = element_Agregar;

    size_agrega++;

    printf("El arreglo con el elemento agregado es: ");

    for(j=0; j<size_agrega; j++)
    {
        printf("%3d",c[j]);
    }
}
```

La primera cosa rara que se ve es:

```
 c[size_agrega] = element_Agregar;
```

¿Por qué motivo esa instrucción es peligrosa?

Porque `n`, que es el tamaño del arreglo, se está pasando por valor a `borrarElemento`, luego la instrucción (`--size_borra`) no dejará de ser un cambio local que no afectará para nada al valor de `n`.

Un pequeño ejemplo ilustrativo:

```
void func(int valor)
{ valor = 1000; }

int main()
{
  int n = 0;
  func(n);
  printf("%d",n); // imprime 0
}
```

La consecuencia de esto es que el valor ´size_agrega´ va a coincidir con el tamaño del arreglo. En el ejemplo que estamos siguiendo en esta respuesta será 3, luego la instrucción que te comento se traducirá en:

```
c[3] = element_Agregar;
```

`c[3]` no pertenece al arreglo. Ahora estás escribiendo fuera de tu arreglo.

Entiendo que tu idea en este caso es que `borrarElemento` actualizase `n`, de tal forma que esta función debería ser capaz de añadir el nuevo elemento al final del arreglo.

Para conseguir esto tienes que pasarle un puntero a `borrarElemento`:

```
void borrarElemento(int b[], int* size_borra, int element_Borrar)
{
    for(j=0; j<*size_borra; j++)
    {
        // ...
        --*size_borra;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Y la correspondiente llamada quedaría así:

```
borrarElemento(array, &n, elemento_Borr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Realmente estás sumando uno a la posición después de agregar el valor:

```
c[size_agrega] = element_Agregar;
size_agrega++;
```

Lo tendrías que hacer así:

```
size_agrega++;
c[size_agrega] = element_Agregar;
```

ya que sino te va a sobrescribir el valor que tengas en la última posición del array en vez de añadirte el nuevo valor en la posición `n+1` del array.

Comment: si te fijas, en `borrarElemento( )` *desplaza* los elementos 1 posición, para tapar el hueco dejado por el elemento borrado.

Comment: @Trauma Sí, me he dado cuenta. Sin embargo, también es verdad que creo que quiere que los métodos funcionen por separado ya que el OP recalca que _El problema que tengo es con la última acción, la cual es agregar un elemento al final del arreglo.

Lo que ocurre es que, **al agregar el elemento al arreglo, el elemento anterior a ese es completamente diferente al que inicialmente estaba.**_ Además, si no quisiera agregar los métodos por separado no tendría ningún sentido que usara `size_agrega++` después para luego recorrer el bucle e intentar mostrar un valor que no existiría (el último).

Comment: Antes no entendia del todo la pregunta, y ahora menos. Lo que yo veo en agregaElemento es que puede tener errores al mostrar el contenido, por size_agrega++, que puede mostrar 1 dato mas alla del tamaño del array.

Comment: @Trauma Bueno, realmente creo que lo más sensato será esperar a que el OP responda con una cosa u otra. Sin embargo, uno de los dos errores los tiene en su código (depende de lo que realmente quiera hacer).

Comment: Cierto. A ver si acepta tu respuesta o comenta algo, para iluminarnos (que ya es de noche xD).